# occurence of count of \n (new line ) in a string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am having a Multi line string(NSSTRING) as below

11501 W SHAWNEE MISSION PKWY

P.O. BOX 3179

Shawnee Mission KS 66203

9132482287

here the line has three \n (3 new lines). Here i want is count of \n .

I googled a lot but could not find it .

Thanks, 
Mrugen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here might you get the answer

[NSString : number of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370574/nsstring-number-of-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate through the characters in the string and count the number of them that are `\n`. Another is to split the string on `\n`, count the number of substrings, and subtract 1. You can do either with [NSString's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) API.