# Number of white spaces in string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How can I calculate the number of whitespaces in a String (e.g. "How are you?") in Objective-C?

Answer (score 8):

You could do this:

```
[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] count]
```

Also, see this question for a couple of other solutions: [Number of occurrences of a substring in an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166809/number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just get the number of whitespaces between words, you can do `[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] count] - 1` (there will always be 1 less space than there are words).

However, that will only get the number of whitespaces between words, not the total number of spaces (i.e. `" How are you ?   "` will 3 spaces, which is fine if that's what you need). If you want the total number of spaces in the string, though, go with looping through it.

```
NSUInteger spaces = 0;
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [string length]; index++) {
    if ([string characterAtIndex:index] == ' ') {
        spaces++;
    }
}
```

That will produce 11 for `"_How__are_you___?___"` (the code formatter deletes extra spaces in a line, so I had to show spaces with underscores).