# How to get a number of spaces in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to get a number of space, how can I get that quickly? I don't want to do this by the following code.

```
NSString *str = @"";
// for example I want to get a string with 10 spaces
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    str= [str stringByAppendingString:@" "];
}
```

I think the code is not an efficient one. who can give me another more efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[@"" stringByPaddingToLength:10 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] count]

Also, see this question for a couple of other solutions: [Number of occurrences of a substring in an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166809/number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-an-nsstring)