# How do I search many words in a text in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, string, search

my code

```
NSString * mistring = @"hello hello hello.";
 NSRange detect; detect = [mistring rangeOfString: @"@hello"]; 
if (detect.location == NSNotFound) 
{ NSLog(@"Not Found."); 
}else{ NSLog (@"Se ha encontrado una coincidencia en la posición: %i", detectar.location); NSLog (@"Está tiene %i caracteres.", detectar.length); }
```

this code only show 1 "hello"
but i need the app show me 3 "hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSUInteger count = 0, length = [str length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length); 
while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
  range = [str rangeOfString: @"cake" options:0 range:range];
  if(range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
    range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
    count++; 
  }
}
```

[Number of occurrences of a substring in an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166809/number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-an-nsstring)

Comment: This doesn't do any counting.