# NSString and all occurrence of word in text

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder if there is a "iOS API way" to find in custom NSString string range of every occurrence of word, e.x.

```
var text: NSString = "John is tall. John is 23."
```

When I use:

```
text.rangeOfString("John")
```

it will return only first one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166809/number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-an-nsstring

Comment: "it will return only first one." - Apple Doku: `rangeOfString:
Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver.`

Comment: Why does this get down voted? This is a legit question.

Comment: Why are you using NSString?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus There is nothing wrong with using `NSString` in a Swift application.

Comment: There is nothing wrong using String also

Comment: There is no need to use NSString here. He should always use String Array Doubles and Int. This is Swift not Objective-c

Comment: BTW Swift is a type-inferred language. Give it a try !!!

Comment: If it would be better for him to use NSString why does Swift uses String when you let it choose?

Comment: Swift sits on top of Cocoa and Cocoa's primary string type is `NSString`. Personally I find `NSString` a lot easier to deal with. Specially when it comes to manipulation and regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple extension on NSString that lets you find occurrences of a substring in a more easy, more Swifty, way:

```
extension NSString {
    func findAllOccurrencesOfString(string: NSString, options: NSStringCompareOptions, _ callback: (NSRange) -> Void) {
        var searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
        while true {
            let range = self.rangeOfString(string, options: options, range: searchRange)
            if range.location == NSNotFound {
                break
            }
            callback(range)
            searchRange = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, self.length - (range.location + range.length))
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can use as:

```
let s: NSString = "John is tall. John is 23. Where is John"
s.findAllOccurrencesOfString("John", options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros) { (range) -> Void in
    println("Found \(s.substringWithRange(range)) at \(range)")
}
```

This results in:

```
Found John at (0,4)
Found John at (14,4)
Found John at (35,4)
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

There is several ways to do so, you can do it with :

- Range ;
- Regular Expression ;
- ...

For example, with regular expression :

```
var str = "John is tall. John is 23."

var length = countElements(str)

var regex : NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "John", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
var nbMatch : Int = regex.numberOfMatchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, length))

println(nbMatch)
```

*Note that you can specify option, here it's case insensitive for example (so "John" or "john" will return the same).*

Answer (score -1):

I think there is nothing in NSString to do this.
Try a loop clipping the string each time "John" is found and adding the range to NSMutableArray.

Comment: There is no need to clip the string. Just pass a new range to `rangeOfString:options:range:`.

Comment: This is a very bad answer. There are a number of options in `NSString` to find occurrences of substrings or regular expression matches.